# Displaying 2D arrays of pixel values in a console application

Tags: c, image, sockets, tcp, multidimensional-array

I'm continuously sending 2D arrays of pixel values (uint32) from LabVIEW to a C-program through TCP/IP with the resolution 160x120. The purpose of the C-program is to display the received pixel values as 2D arrays in the console application. I'm sending the pixels as stream of bytes, and using the recv function in Ws2_32.lib to receive the bytes in the C-program. Then I'm converting the bytes to uint32 values and displaying them in the console application using a 2D arrays, so every 2D array will represent an image.

I have en issue with the frame rate though. I'm able to send 30 frames per second in LabVIEW, but when I open the TCP/IP connection with the C-program, the frame rate goes down to 1 frame per second. It must be an issue with the C-program, since I managed to send the desired frames per second with the same LabVIEW program to a corresponding C# program.

The C-code:

```
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 256
#define IMAGEX 120
#define IMAGEY 160 

WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET s , new_socket;
struct sockaddr_in server , client;
int c;
int iResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
unsigned int x=0,y=0,i,n;
uint32_t image[IMAGEX][IMAGEY];
size_t len;
uint32_t* p;

p = (uint32_t*)recvbuf;

do
{

iResult = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

len = iResult/sizeof(uint32_t);

for(i=0; i < len; i++)
{
    image[x][y] = p[i];
    x++;
    if (x >= IMAGEX)
    {
        x=0;
        y++;
    }
    if (y >= IMAGEY)
    {
        y = 0;
        x = 0;
        //print image
        for (n=0; n< IMAGEX*IMAGEY; n++)
        {
            printf("%d",image[n%IMAGEX][n/IMAGEY]);
            if (n % IMAGEX)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }

    }
}

} while ( iResult > 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

try reducing the prints .. Since you are reading and printing in the same thread, the data in the TCP connection will fill up and it will then back pressure the other end (LABView) and the LABView will stop sending data until it gets the green signal from the other end (you C program)

To start with you can debug by replacing this

```
    for (n=0; n< IMAGEX*IMAGEY; n++)
    {
        printf("%d",image[n%IMAGEX][n/IMAGEY]);
        if (n % IMAGEX)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

with 
        printf("One frame recv\n");

and see if it makes any difference. I am assuming your tcp connection has ample bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to diagnose without further information.  I can give a few suggestions, however.

First of all, your recv call is using a small buffer, so you are spending a lot of time calling it.  Why not read a whole frame at a time?  Also, you read in the data and then copy it to the image array.  Wouldn't it be simpler to just use the image array itself?  Combining those two suggestions would have recv reading a full frame directly into the image array, saving a lot of time.

Another source of the problem could be the console.  With the sample code you provided, you are attempting to write 30*120*160=57,600 integer values per second to the terminal.  If the average value, with delimiter, takes up 8 characters, that's 4 million characters per second.  It's entirely possible that the display just can't go that fast, in which case things would back up and slow down all the way to the server writing to the socket.
There are several ways to handle this, but it's too much to go into here.

Comment: Regarding the part about copying to the image array. What do you exactly mean by using the image array itself ?.

Comment: recv(new_socket, (void *)image, IMAGEX*IMAGEY*sizeof(uint32_t), 0);